# Problems installing logstash-filter-translate

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, fedora-25

OS: Fedora 25
ELK stack version : 5.2 (only with kibanaa+logstash+elasticsearch+filebeat)

Note: I don't have a proxy configured in my network.
So the following known problem and solutions is not applied: 
[known bug](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/6044)

Trying to install the logstash-filter-translate as following:

```
DEBUG=1 bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-translate
```

I get the following error :

```
0:  ruby-maven (3.3.12) from /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/specifications/ruby-maven-3.3.12.gemspec
  jar dependencies for logstash-core-event-java-5.2.2-java.gemspec . . .

Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted - Operation not permitted
org/jruby/RubyFile.java:1102:in `utime'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:1389:in `copy_metadata'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:466:in `copy_entry'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:1443:in `preorder_traverse'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:462:in `copy_entry'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:521:in `mv'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:1525:in `fu_each_src_dest'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:1541:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:1523:in `fu_each_src_dest'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:508:in `mv'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/ruby-maven-3.3.12/lib/ruby_maven.rb:84:in `launch'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/ruby-maven-3.3.12/lib/ruby_maven.rb:39:in `exec'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler.rb:245:in `with_clean_env'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler.rb:232:in `with_original_env'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler.rb:238:in `with_clean_env'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/ruby-maven-3.3.12/lib/ruby_maven.rb:38:in `exec'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/ruby-maven-3.3.12/lib/maven/ruby/maven.rb:112:in `exec'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/jar-dependencies-0.3.10/lib/jars/maven_exec.rb:79:in `resolve_dependencies_list'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/jar-dependencies-0.3.10/lib/jars/installer.rb:237:in `install_dependencies'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/jar-dependencies-0.3.10/lib/jars/installer.rb:226:in `do_install'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/jar-dependencies-0.3.10/lib/jars/installer.rb:172:in `vendor_jars'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/shared/jars/post_install_hook.rb:28:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:281:in `call'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:215:in `run_hooks'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:214:in `run_hooks'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:195:in `generate_bin'
org/jruby/RubyDir.java:341:in `chdir'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:53:in `chdir'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/1.9/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:52:in `chdir'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:189:in `generate_bin'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:73:in `install'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:107:in `install_gem_from_spec'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:269:in `install_sequentially'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/1.9/forwardable.rb:201:in `each'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:268:in `install_sequentially'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:90:in `run'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:18:in `install'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:80:in `run'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/cli.rb:155:in `install'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
/usr/share/logstash/lib/bootstrap/bundler.rb:152:in `execute_bundler'
/usr/share/logstash/lib/bootstrap/bundler.rb:113:in `invoke!'
/usr/share/logstash/lib/pluginmanager/install.rb:142:in `install_gems_list!'
/usr/share/logstash/lib/pluginmanager/install.rb:61:in `execute'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:67:in `run'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/subcommand/execution.rb:11:in `execute'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:67:in `run'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:132:in `run'
/usr/share/logstash/lib/pluginmanager/main.rb:46:in `(root)'
Bundler::InstallError: An error occurred while installing logstash-core-event-java (5.2.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install logstash-core-event-java -v '5.2.2'` succeeds before bundling.
  install_gem_from_spec at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:145
   install_sequentially at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:269
                   each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613
                   each at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/1.9/forwardable.rb:201
   install_sequentially at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:268
                    run at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:90
                install at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:18
                    run at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:80
                install at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/cli.rb:155
                    run at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27
         invoke_command at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126
               dispatch at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359
                  start at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440
                  start at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10
        execute_bundler at /usr/share/logstash/lib/bootstrap/bundler.rb:152
                invoke! at /usr/share/logstash/lib/bootstrap/bundler.rb:113
     install_gems_list! at /usr/share/logstash/lib/pluginmanager/install.rb:142
                execute at /usr/share/logstash/lib/pluginmanager/install.rb:61
                    run at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:67
                execute at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/subcommand/execution.rb:11
                    run at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:67
                    run at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:132
                 (root) at /usr/share/logstash/lib/pluginmanager/main.rb:46
```

Comment: The first line of the error states "Operation not permitted". Could you retry the installation with `sudo`?

Comment: it work. Thank you.
But it give me this message:
**Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.**

Comment: Did you check my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you different way.
Go to github repository of this plugin.
Then pull it to your local machine.
Then edit the .gem file in your logstash directory. Modify below command and add there.

```
gem "logstash-type-pluginname", :path => "the_path_of_plugin"
```

Then run the below command.

```
bin/logstash-plugin install --no-verify
```

After use this plugin. This way also give you a chance to improve the plugin codes for your purposes.